# If not stackexchange, where can I ask this question?

Tags: discussion

I asked a question on the StackOverflow and the question was put on hold. I understand why, in fact I thought about and did a lot of looking around before I posted the question, but there was simply not another place that I found better suited for the question to be asked and answered.

Here is the question and it is on the topic of ["The best podcasts for developers using Java and Javascript"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28507326/2607501). Like I said, I read the help guide yada yada yada, yes the question could lead a way for discussion and personal opinion; or people could simply answer the question like any other. Many programming questions are opinion based, this question was asked twice in years prior, it is obviously a relevant post and people want to know.

So, if the question must be removed or blocked, where then can I find an answer that is hmmm, *current and relevant*. Let's face it, podcasts series come and go with the technology they're based upon.

Comment: twitter, linkedin, a popular javascript forum/discussion board, stackoverflow chat, pretty much anywhere that isn't a stackoverflow question. I don't think there is a stackexchange site that question would fit into as a question.

Comment: I looked around for ways to make a couple bucks, but I couldn't find any.  So, as I was saying, gimme all of your money.

Comment: The standards for questions asked in 2011 and 2008 are **not** the standards used today.  You cannot judge whether a question is on-topic by seeing if a similar one has been asked before.   The correct approach is to go to the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and see if your question meets the *current* criteria for asking.

Comment: Thanks for the negative feedback I guess, but I asked the question because I honestly want to know.

Comment: "Many programming questions are opinion based." [*citation needed*] Reddit has a a programming subreddit.

Comment: From prog.se meta: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/a/6743/40980

Comment: "Let's face it, podcasts series come and go with the technology they're based upon." That's the real problem. Questions like that won't be useful for future visitors, or at least not for very long, so they don't fit well with the goal of the SE network.

Comment: The questions you referenced from 2008 and 2011 have been closed since 2011. The fact that you feel the need to ask a new question just because it's been a while since those were asked is a good indication that the question is not a good fit for Stack Exchange. We want references that are going to stand the test of time, not lists of links that need to be updated constantly.

Comment: I think @Kevin B was the only one with a good answer here. I'll close the question. I don't have or never use those sites, but maybe I'll start. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That question in particular does not fit into any stackexchange site because it will result in answers that contain subjective lists of results that will very quickly go stale, making any answers to said question rather useless to future visitors. There is no concrete answer to the question. You said it yourself, podcasts come and go very quickly.

I would instead ask that question in a relevant chat channel on stackoverflow, or on a social website or programming forum.