# Can I ask a question about inherent issues with Java? If so, where?

Tags: discussion, scope

I am new to Java, and want to ask the community

1. what they think the prominent warts of Java are,
2. why they exist. (For example, what is the deal with so many empty directories in the default config?

Unlike [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286033/if-not-stackexchange-where-can-i-ask-this-question) my question seems to rely on stable language features and should not quickly go out of date. Is this an acceptable Stack Overflow question, or is there some other Stack Exchange site I should use?

Edit: Unlike the proposed existing answer, I am not asking for a looser stackoverflow.  I am asking about the capacity to get at my intent (a collection of conceptual explanations for what read to me as odd design choices in Java/commonly recognized "warts"/common stumbling blocks in learning the language), instead of my wording (which I don't much care about).

Edit 2: A rephrase of the question that swaps "think" for more empirical concerns might be "Which features most commonly prompt misunderstandings/questions from new learners, and what are the conceptual justifications/problem cases that are necessary to understand that implementation choice?"

Edit 3: I concede that SO is not a place to rely on commonness-based questions, which is the only way around using judgement as in the original phrasing.  Voting to close my own question.

Edit 4: I just realized I know how to answer my own question.  I am describing the set of SO questions asked with a java tag and no other tags, with positive votes and positive votes on an accepted answer, about "modern" java implementations (ie no questions older than X), in descending order by votes.  Thanks to everyone for being so helpful.

Comment: All that appears _opinion based_ for me. I don't think this would go through very far.

Comment: Related question [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323334/is-asking-why-on-language-specifications-still-considered-as-primarily-opinio).

Comment: All the answers you need: 1. It's not C# 2. It's not C#

Comment: If you catch yourself writing a question that could technically have **any answer, depending on who is answering it** it's probably not a good fit for SO. Words like think, feel, best, worst, most popular, industry standard, etc - should be huge red flags.

Comment: @Ares as described in the comments in the first answer, I am trying to pull out things that are well-socialized and described in the community (ex the diamond inheritance description.  Diamond inheritance + nondeterministic resolution order = nondeterministic code execution and heartbreak is not terrible sensitive to who is answering it.)  I am not too concerned with the opinion-ness of the phrasing and am fine with dropping it; my real goal is "what is a compact representation of common 'received wisdom' in Java's design", but struggling with phrasing/admissibility.

Comment: The point I'm making, and the point many others will make, is that whether or not there's a 'right' answer, any time you introduce the opportunity for opinion, you can create bickering and pointless discourse. We want discrete questions with discrete answers.

My only thoughts would be to ask your questions in the smallest, self contained units possible. Even if you eliminate the opinionated aspects of your question, that's still _much_ too broad for the SO format.

Comment: @Ares Thank you for the clarification.  Will I need to go through each thing that looks like a wart to me, ex Java's tendency to generate directories with exactly one subdirectory, and ask "What are some conceptual motivations/problem cases that necessitate <x feature implementation decision>?"

This feels like that would be question spamming.  Also it seems like there is a strongly skewed distribution of features that provoke these questions empirically vs those that don't, and an inability to filter on that criterion seems odd.

Comment: If you ask narrow, complete, well worded questions, you might get somewhere. Be _very_ careful about the questions you ask. Ask questions that people can answer - asking questions about why Java the way it is is like asking aeronautics engineers why Bernoulli's laws work so darn well (or poorly)

Comment: Be sure to leave out any reference to skin conditions when talking about language features ;).

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan  That is fair.  I don't know what a good typifier is for these kinds of things.  I just want to be able to ask questions like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8852623/why-do-java-sources-have-so-many-folders-inside-each-other) en masse, and "wart" is my usual goto for "this looks weird".  The other commenters seem to be saying that this is an impossible class to sufficiently describe.

Comment: @bwarren2: "*"wart" is my usual goto for "this looks weird"*" What "looks weird" is a matter of opinion. Just because something "looks weird" to you doesn't mean it "looks weird" to anyone else. And therefore, your question is based on opinions about the language, not facts.

Comment: @NicolBolas While that is my shorthand phrasing, I do think it should be possible to sufficiently and uniquely describe variant practices that are common, unexplained stumbling blocks.  The linked "what is with all these folders" question is, I wager, ~infinitely more like to be in this category than "what is with using characters to write code instead of mere 1's and 0's" (which "looks weird" to approx. no one).  This tells me there is at least a two-category system, and part of my question is how to describe what (I think) we know I mean.  EDIT: and we can validate my guess with the link.

Comment: 1. Oracle 2. Oracle

Comment: You might have [better luck at Quora](https://www.quora.com/Why-do-some-programmers-hate-Java-1).

Answer (score 11):

These are not suitable questions for our sites.

You are asking for opinions. We expect questions that have objectively correct answers, not ones where every answer is equally valid.

Your second question (why something is the way it is) - apart from getting opinions, the only people who can answer with authority are those who made the decision. This is unlikely to be people on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Are the core Java devs the only ones qualified to talk about single-inheritance vs the diamond inheritance problem?  That seems strange to me.

Comment: @bwarren2 when you ask things like "why is the language having this problem?" It comes down to how it was implemented. Hard for non Java devs to answer that...

Comment: I think there is a distinction between conceptual choices and implementation problems.  The diamond inheritance example does not rely on the particulars of the Java implementation, only the ideas of inheritance themselves.

Comment: @bwarren2 and that should be language agnostic. When you specifically ask why is JAVA having this issue, you aren't asking how the concept works, but how one language's implementation doesn't circumvent it.

Comment: @bwarren2:  It very much does depend on the particulars of the language, since the language designers could have went the route of Scala (another JVM language) and solved the diamond problem in that way.  However, we can't give you an objective answer as to why they did it since we weren't privy to that discussion nearly 20 years ago.

Comment: @Makoto is there a an acceptable question that would get the usual "diamond inheritance without resolution order produces nondeterministic example, <sample code>" answer, or is that entire mode of inquiry precluded?  If it is possible to get that answer, is there an acceptable question that would pool it and other explanations for things like nullable core types, empty directories, etc?  I really want to ask "what is the full extent of this weirdness, with sympathetic considerations to do it that way" to improve my mental model of Java beyond "is riddled with strangeness".

Comment: Counterargument: [Brian Goetz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3553087/brian-goetz) is here and has answered many "Why'd they do it that way?" questions about the Java libraries.  The Java mailing lists are open and I've used them to support [a very popular answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24603187/3614835).  Older decisions are harder to find rationale for; I don't know of a Java resource analogous to The Design and Evolution of C++, but I wouldn't rule out those questions entirely. (Asking about any and all warts is just too broad.)

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom your "counterargument" is somewhat strange - post states that getting correct answer on historical question is unlikely, and you counter that you've managed to provide one good answer to one such question...  Sounds like pro- rather than counter- to me. (Historical questions are known to be on-topic - http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260711/should-why-language-feature-designed-particular-way-be-closed-moved)

Answer (score 5):

> what they **think** the prominent warts of Java are

This word singlehandedly qualifies the question as ['too opinion based'](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/).

> why they exist

This is best answered by the development team *behind* Java, not the Stack Overflow community.

Comment: If I instead used "which warts of implementation commonly cause stumbling during pedagogy", is it no longer opinion based?

Comment: @bwarren2 _""which warts of implementation commonly cause stumbling during pedagogy""_ Rarely. What are correct pedagogical methods is primarily _opinion based as well_. _<sarcasm>I prefer the good ole' corporal punishment</sarcasm>_.